# How to insert larger number (over 100 million) of dummy records into database table quickly?

Tags: sql, oracle, dummy-data

For testing purposes I need to insert over 100 million records to a table. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Depends on the data you want. A recursive cte can sometimes be used. Do you have the data, or do you want to generate it?

Comment: Hi, I want ot generate it.

Comment: Write a script, or stored procedure, or recursive cte. Come back with a new questions if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: Just side note while inserting the data make sure you consider the tablespace of undo and how you are inserting the data,, if you are inserting one bulk of 100 million the undo need handle the 100 mil in one shot. for performance depends on the hardwar you are using for example ssd is better then hdd sata. as for dummy record you can use dbms meta data in oracle and have them. or CTE as the guys suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, datetime)
SELECT LEVEL,
       'XYZ' || LPAD(LEVEL, 10, '0'),
       DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * (LEVEL - 1)
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100000000;
```

or a recursive query:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (id, name, datetime)
WITH rsqfc (id) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT id + 1 FROM DUAL WHERE id < 100000000
)
SELECT id,
       'XYZ' || LPAD(id, 10, '0'),
       DATE '1970-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * (id - 1)
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: The `LEVEL` trick is a neat way to generate fake rows. However, for 100,000,000 rows it will likely generate the error "ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation". In that case, you may need to loop through multiple inserts that handle a smaller number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use an external tool to generate text file with rows in convenient format to be later imported with SQLLDR in direct mode, you can split the file to run several processes in parallel (parallel=true parameter, version 23c has even a new parameter to import in parallel from 1 invocation).
Look also at transportable tablespaces to avoid downtime if you can do the import  in a non-live system and attach them later to the final instance.